# ampscript for count by field variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

The marketing team have an event where customers are asked to fill in a SmartCapture form and in the form the customer can add guest details (so max 2 people per row entry). They want to record the running capacity as in a journey we have a decision spilt when it hits a certain number of people (the event/session limit - marked below as @MAX_DAY...), but I can't use the RowCount function due to a record sometimes being 2 people (due to the guest).

Does anyone know how to add all the "counts" together (by session) as my below event/session counts are wrong currently as based on rowCount (@EVENT_COUNT_D1_S1 for session 1 and @EVENT_COUNT_D1_S2 for session 2). Thankyou

```ampscripot
SET @PLUS1_FIRST_NAME = AttributeValue("PLUS1_FIRST_NAME") 
SET @fpsid = RequestParameter('fpsid')
SET @sfmc_id = RequestParameter('sfmc_id')
SET @localeLookupResult = LookupRows('ent.EVENT_TEXT_TRANSLATIONS', 'LOCALE', @LOCALE)
SET @localeLookupCount = RowCount(@localeLookupResult)
SET @LOCALE = RequestParameter('LOCALE')

IIF EMPTY(@LOCALE) then 
    SET @LOCALE = AttributeValue('LOCALE') 
ENDIF

IIF EMPTY(@LOCALE) THEN 
    SET @LOCALE = 'en-hk' 
ENDIF

IIF EMPTY(@PLUS1_FIRST_NAME) THEN 
    SET @RECORD_NUMBER = '1' 
ELSE 
    SET @RECORD_NUMBER = '2' 
ENDIF

SET @MAX_DAY1_SESSION_1 = "14" SET @MAX_DAY1_SESSION_2 = "14"
SET @MAX_DAY1_SESSION_3 = "14" set @S1 = "1100-1300" 
SET @S2 = "1500-1700" SET @SESSION_DATE = AttributeValue("SESSION_DATE") 
SET @SESSION_TIME = AttributeValue("SESSION_TIME") 
SET @EVENT_NAME = "202402_B-Triple-C"

IIF RequestParameter("SESSION_TIME") == "1100-1300" THEN 
    set @EVENT_COUNT_D1_S1 = rowCount(LOOKUPROWS('EVENT_TABLE','EVENT_NAME',@EVENT_NAME,'SESSION_TIME','1100-1300')) 
    set @COUNT_S1 = Subtract(@MAX_DAY1_SESSION_1,@EVENT_COUNT_D1_S1) 
    set @CAPACITY_D1_S1 = Subtract(@COUNT_S1,@RECORD_NUMBER) 
ELSEIF RequestParameter("SESSION_TIME") == "1500-1700" THEN 
    set @EVENT_COUNT_D1_S2 = rowCount(LOOKUPROWS('EVENT_TABLE','EVENT_NAME',@EVENT_NAME,'SESSION_TIME','1500-1700')) 
    set @COUNT_S2 = Subtract(@MAX_DAY1_SESSION_2,@EVENT_COUNT_D1_S2) 
    set @CAPACITY_D1_S2 = Subtract(@COUNT_S2,@RECORD_NUMBER) 
else 
ENDIF
```